# Why do printed characters disappear in this python code?

Tags: python, string, object, printing

(This question rised from an attempt to get around [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346430/how-do-i-keep-python-from-printing-type-information))

I'm trying to print a list of dictionaries in python.
Since I can't find a real function which is able to convert a python object to a string (no, json.dumps doesn't work), I thought to write a simple printing script.

Unfortunately characters at the beginning of the line simply disappear...
Now, I'm probably no expert in python, but this behavior looks nonsense to me.

```
# The out object is returned by a library (rekall) 
# and it is a list of dictionaries.
import rekall
out = rekall.a_modified_module.calculate()

print '[',
for ps in out:
    first = True
    print '{',
    for info in ps:
        if first:
            first = False
        else:
            print '\'%s\':\'%s\',' % (info, ps[info]),
    print '}',
print ']'
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
[{'pid':'2040', 'name':'leon.exe', 'offset':'2234185984',}]
```

Instead I get this:

```
'pid':'2040', 'name':'leon.exe', 'offset':'2234185984',}]
```

Can you please explain me what's happening here? (I'm skipping first line in the loop because it contains another dictionary and the output gets even crazier, with mixed parts of the output)

P.S.: if you have a valid option for printing a generic python object (something comparable to JSON.stringify in javascript, but without having to deal with JSON objects) please tell me.

EDIT: My question aims at explaining this strange (to me) behavior,
where the output depends on what is printed after the brackets.
In fact, if I remove the inner for loop ("for info in ps"), the initial brackets are printed correctly.
Also, if I create a pipe to send the output to another program, that program will receive the output correctly, starting from the brackets.

EDIT: To help understanding the nature of the problem, and the type of the 'out' object, this is the output using the 'pprint' module:

```
[{'name':  [String:ImageFileName]: 'leon.exe\x00',
  'offset': 2236079360,
  'pid':  [unsigned int:UniqueProcessId]: 0x000007FC,
  'psscan': {'CSRSS': False,
             'Handles': False,
             'PsActiveProcessHead': True,
             'PspCidTable': True,
             'Sessions': True}}]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem. In particular, what value of `out` produces the output you're getting?

Comment: How is json.dumps not working ?

Comment: Please share the content of your JSON object (the one you passed to `json.dumps()`)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't print your list-of-dicts using `print(out[1:])`?

Comment: The `pprint` module does pretty printing. It may be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Your code has indentation errors that keep us from following the logic. It also unilaterally does `print '[',` so that `[` has to be in the output. Since its not there, its clear that you are not showing us the problematic code. Its better to post a working example than some pseudo-code.

Comment: "I can't find a real function which is able to convert a python object to a string" You don't appear to suggest JSON as a requirement, and your expected output is not pprint. What is wrong with `a = [{1:2, 3:4}, {5:6, 7:8}]` and then `print str(a)`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay but i'm really busy lately.
Just a few clarifications (I will update my post as soon as possible):
1) The out object is not a JSON object (neither I said so). It's just a list of dictionaries, but the elements are actually only strings and numbers (as for I understand).
2) The print(out[1:]) form didn't work. I don't remember the reason. I will try it again.

Comment: @roganjosh: Your solution is definitively more elegant than mine :) I will try it soon. Still I have the curiosity of understanding why the first brackets won't show up!

Comment: @tdelaney: 
- thanks, I will try with the pprint module
- where's the indentation error?

Comment: Just a couple of things more: 
- If I don't print anything inside the brackets (that is i remove the 'for info in ps' loop, the brackets are actually showed correctly.
- If I create a pipe (from a C program) and connect it to the python executable and then let it run the script, I correctly receive the first brackets.

Comment: @FedeFranz - I don't think the code you posted is the code you use or you would have seen the indentation error. I suggest you copy/paste from your question and run it. The indentation error is obvious. Once that is fixed, you'll see that the initial bracket is printed.

Comment: @tdelaney I now see the indentation error, sorry (I will now correct it in the question). However, the original code is the exactly the same (without the indentation error) and the initial brackets are not printed at all.

Anyway, my question aims at explaining this strange (to me) behavior,
where the output depends on what is printed after the brackets (if I remove the inner for loop ("for info in ps"), the initial brackets are printed correctly).

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a way we can duplicate? I don't know the `rekall` module... is it the [Rekall Memory Forensic Framework](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rekall/1.5.3.post1)? One possibility is that this `rekall` module is writing some garbage to stdout. If it writes an escape, for instance, the console may be interpreting the bracket as the start of a color code. In that case, its sent but supressed by the console. Take that module out and see what happens. Then you know its a problem with the module not the code you show.

Comment: @Kevin Using print(out[1:]) I get ' [ ] ' as the output.

Comment: @tdelaney I tried defining the 'out' object manually, but in that case the outuput is correct. So I'm afraid I'm not able to provide a full working code.

I guess what you're saying is right, that rekall puts some strange character. And I agree with you, the problem does not reside in the code itself, but in the output of the invoked function.Actually, this is exactly what I'd like to know: if there are chacters, that if printed AFTER the bracket, will prevent such brackets to be shown.

Comment: @FedeFranz - the backspace would do that. Try `print "[{\b\b'pid'"` to see what I mean. After piping output to a file, if you `cat filename`,  the backspaces will still mask the first chars. But you could go into the python shell and do `print repr(open('filename').read())`

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks. I guess rekall puts some of these escape characters and this is what mess up the output. 
I still don't get why I don't receive these characters when getting the output through a pipe, but I think your point answer my question.

If you want to post a brief explanation of this issue I will accept it as the definitive answer. If not, please tell me, and I will write it myself :)

P.S.: If you're interested, I added a reference at the beginning of the question, to the problem that brought me to write this code.

Comment: I'll write an answer but I'm still puzzled exactly how this happens. You aren't just missing the opening brackets, you are missing the entire `"psscan"` key suggesting that a `\r` carriage return is written just prior to `'pid'`. But I don't see how that happens. Try a manual `repr` of the data: `print '\'%s\':\'%s\',' % (repr(str(info)), repr(str(ps[info])))`. It will "stringify" the rekall object to get rid of its formatting but `repr` it again so we can see any embedded meta characters. rekall may be changing its behavior if its being piped but this trick should confound it.

Comment: The "psscan" key is skipped on purpose by the loop code (with the "First" trick).
I added it, because when trying to print that key too, the output got even more confused, with parts of text mixing each other.
This is what I get when not skipping the 'psscan' key:
`'pid':'2044', 'name':'leon.exe', 'offset':'2236079360', }, ]ocessHead': True, 'PspCidTable': True, 'Sessions': True}',`

Comment: That only skips the `psscan` key by luck - dict keys are not ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Python objects have two methods used to get a quick human-readable representation of its data: [str](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) which gives *a nicely printable representation of an object* and [repr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) which attempts to give a string that could be used to rebuild the object: *For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval()*. Heavy emphassis on "attempts". Classes are free to override the default implementation with their own `__str__` and `__repr__` methods.

Your example output:

```
'name':  [String:ImageFileName]: 'leon.exe\x00'
```

is interesting. It shows that the `rekall` module is overriding `__repr__` to give a more complex view of its data types (`[String:ImageFileName]:`). But that's not valid python - the implementors were just giving a more typeful description. It also shows that its strings `'leon.exe\x00'` have non-printable characters in them. It means that, in this instance, a NUL `\x00` is emitted when printing the string value of the data. I would call this a bug - but it could be that the module is supposed to emit raw binary data.

Non-printable characters may be used for formatting by your console. For instance, `\r` (carriage return) tells the console to reposition at the start of the line and overwrite characters

```
>>> print 'foo\rbar'
bar
```

On my console, this escape sequence

```
>>> print '\x1b[0;31;40m hello'
hello
```

makes "hello" print in red.

If `rekall` is putting out raw binary data, strings you are trying to print have non-printable characters that mess up your console display. To keep things complicated, the `rekall` module may be checking whether its `stdout` is a terminal and changing its output to add fancy terminal-oriented formatting to its strings.

Assuming that `rekall` is putting raw binary data in strings you could do `str` to get rid of `rekall` metadata and then `repr` to escape the troublesome characters

```
def mystr(s):
    return repr(str(s))

for ps in out:
    first = True
    for info in ps:
        if first:
            first = False
        else:
            print '\'%s\':\'%s\'' % (mystr(info), mystr(ps[info])))
```

Or write your own function to filter out characters you don't want. This is kinda difficult in Unicode but for ascii text we could take a subset of the characters you would find in `string.printable`.

```
printable = set(
    '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$'
    '%&\\\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t')

def mystr(s):
    return ''.join(filter(printable.__contains__, str(s)))

for ps in out:
    first = True
    for info in ps:
        if first:
            first = False
        else:
            print '\'%s\':\'%s\'' % (mystr(info), mystr(ps[info])))
```