# How do I keep Python from printing type information?

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

(This question is somehow related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266308/why-do-printed-characters-disappear-in-this-python-code).)

I have an object 'o', which is returned from a third-party module (whose code is quite intricate).
When printing this object I get this output:

```
>>> print(o)
[{'pid':  [unsigned int:UniqueProcessId]: 0x000007FC, 'name':  [String:ImageFileName]: 'leon.exe\x00', 'offset': 2236079360}]
```

As far as I understand, this is a list of dictionaries. 
However, the output also contains some additional type information (e.g.: [unsigned int:UniqueProcessId]) that prevents me to parse this output with the 'ast' module (i.e. by using ast.literal_eval() function).

My question is: how can I avoid this type information to be printed out?
That is I want to get this output:

```
>>> smartprint(o)
[{'pid': 0x000007FC, 'name': 'leon.exe', 'offset': 2236079360}]
```

Additionaly: can you explain me why is this info printed out and what it actually represents?
If I print the single values in a loop like in this code:

```
    for ps in out:
    first = True
    for info in ps:
        if first:
            first = False
        else:
            print '\'%s\':\'%s\'' % (info, ps[info])
```

I don't get any additional type information. Instead what I get is:

```
'pid':'2044'
'name':'leon.exe'
'offset':'2236079360'
```

Why?

Comment: Try `%r` instead of `%s`.

Comment: Your values aren't ordinary integers and strings. They're some other weird types. Look at the documentation for wherever you got those values. Note that whatever you do with this dict, `ast.literal_eval` won't be able to reconstruct the original dict from your output, since it doesn't know how to produce whatever weird objects you're using as values. You could reconstruct something similar with ordinary Python types for the values, though.

Comment: Are you defining this `o` object's class yourself, or is it defined in some 3rd-party module? If it's your own class, you should write a better `__repr__` &/or `__str__` method for it. If it's  3rd-party class you can write a wrapper class for it with new `__repr__` &/or `__str__` methods.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for your answer.
This is exactly the problem I have. I would like to get an output without these weird type information, so to have ast.literal_eval work correctly.
I don't need to reproduce the same object, I just need it to parse it and create a simple list of dictionaries (with all string values).

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for your suggestion.

It's received from a 3rd-party module.
I actually don't know how to write a wrapper class and to redifine those methods, but I guess this is a viable option to have the output to be shown correctly.
I just wonder if it is possible to jave have the print function (or any alternative) to just print the values, so to have a parsable output.

Comment: You can read about `__repr__` & `__str__` in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__). As for creating a wrapper class, take a look at the section on classes in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html), especially the stuff about inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the TYPES are verbose info that is not a part of the key's value. I would suggest use the build in type function .

```
data = {"hello": 1}
# print the type for the object
print(type(data))

# to get for each key,val
for k,v in data.iteritems():
    print(type(k), type(v))
```

Output:

```
<type 'dict'>
(<type 'str'>, <type 'int'>)
```

Comment: The OP is not asking how to print the type of a variable

Comment: As Chris_Rands said, I just want the values, in the same form of the normal 'print' output, but without the type information.